# I want to build a Hyperledger Fabric network running on multiple hosts with multiple organizations

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

I was following Abdul Wahab's tutorial: Hyperledger Fabric on Multiple Hosts [here](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f). He had one organization with two peers.

It all worked fine for me until I tried to create two organizations each having 1 peer. I changed crypto-config.yaml, configtx.yaml and bmhn.sh and I’m pretty sure they’re right (In configtx.yaml, I added org2 with anchor peer0 and port 7051. In script.sh, I added CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051). Is there something wrong with the ports? 
And should I change something in the commands he provided? (For example in 6. Peer1, I changed org1 to org2 when necessary but I haven’t touched the port numbers). I think the problem is with the ports…
Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you try opening up all the ports for docker swarm network as well? Also, is this one peer behaving both as an Endorsing Peer as well as Anchor Peer?

Comment: Yes it is an anchor peer. And for the endorsing peer shouldn't I install a chaincode on the peer for it to become endorsing? (If so, I didn't get to that part because I couldn't connect the two peers). And no I didn't try to open the ports. I just followed the tutorial and it worked fine with one organization but I wanted two and I think the problem is with the ports. Do you know what I should change? @MrudavShukla

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to run two org setup on multiple hosts, you'll need to do the following:

1. Open up the ports #2377(TCP), #7946(TCP+UDP) and #4789(UDP) for docker swarm network.
2. Create swarm from one of the hosts and make the other host join this swarm network.
3. Create an overlay network.
4. Make sure your docker-compose file for fabric components like orderers, peers, ca, couchdb and optionally cli joins this overlay network. These components should be configured to connect to the external network.
5. Spinup docker containers for fabric components on both the hosts.
6. Run "docker network inspect " on both the hosts to check if all the containers have joined the correct network.

By the end, you should be having a multi-org setup on multiple hosts ready.